# If $\iota$ is the embedding of $\mathbb R^{k-1}$ into $\mathbb R^k$, can we simplify $\det(\iota^\ast\circ A\ast\iota)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $k\in\mathbb N$, $A\in\mathbb R^{k\times k}$, $\iota$ denote the canonical embedding of $\mathbb R^{k-1}$ into $\mathbb R^k$ with $\iota\mathbb R^{k-1}=\partial H^k$ and $\pi$ denote the canonical projection of $\mathbb R^k$ onto $\mathbb R^{k-1}$ with $\pi(\partial H^k)=\mathbb R^{k-1}$.

> Is there a useful property of the determinant which allows us to simplify $\det(\pi\circ A\circ\iota)$?

It might be useful to observe that $\iota^\ast=\pi$.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant of $\pi\circ A\circ\iota$ is determined by stripping away the last column and the last row of $A$, and calculating the determinant of the remaining $(k-1) \times (k-1)$ matrix. That's what $\pi\circ A\circ\iota$ does to $A$. I don't think there is any easier way of doing it.